# Can I replace the icon in the window list in the MATE panel?

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate

I am running with the MATE desktop environment and I would like to be able to replace the icon that is show in the "window list" widget on the MATE Panel with one of my choosing:

[image]

How can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Change it how? Delete it, replace it, swap it with another one, move it somewhere else? Please [edit] your question explaining it further.

Comment: I have edited my question- I would like to be able to replace the icon in the panel with one of my choosing.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I posted an answer, but to my surprise, the set icon is different from other distro's. I'll remove my answer for now, but will find out tomorrow how to change the icon if no one did by then.

Comment: Related: http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Thumbnail